# Load .usd files from Nividia Omniverse into Unreal Engine 5.2 with Python Automation

Tags: python, import, automation, unreal-engine5, omniverse

I have a Unreal Engine 5.2 project where i want to load an animation generated with Nvidia Omniverse into Unreal Engine so i can use it for objects in the scene. I already installed the bridge to manuelly import .usd files.

Any idea how to automate this importing process with python?

I allready have the .usd file generated, i just needed to load it automated into the project.

Can anyone help me out with that, would be great!

Thanks a lot!

I only found the old documentation which did not work and chatgpt also does not give any useful solutions. There is hardly any content about it on the web till today. Wouldbe great if you can give an example code and a description what which code means. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have no real tries till now. I thought maybe someone else had the same problem and could help. thanks!

Comment: If you are using OV with Unreal you should be using the appropriate Unreal Connector for this kind of thing. Unreal has one of the best bi-directional connectors.